# Netty: What is the process lifecycle of a channel in netty?

Tags: netty, channel

I am learning Netty recently. I have encountered a problem that is I put a BlockingQueue in ChannelInboundHandler.channelActive method.

Aimed at that I want to get message from BlockingQueue and then send the message to the channel, but the fact is that only one message is sent to the server.
Here is the code below:

```
@Override
public void channleActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception{
   String msg = null;
   while(true){
      msg=msgQueue.take();
      ctx.writeAndFlush(Unpooled.copiedBuffer(msg, CharsetUtil.UTF_8));
   }
}
```

But it doesn't work, I get only one response from the `channelRead()` method.
Is my understanding of netty lifecycle wrong? Can someone help me and explain this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code will basically "block" in `channelActive` which means the `EventLoop` will never be able to do anything else. This is not allowed.

Comment: Thanks!But I still do not know the whole process procedure of a write message in the channel, do you know the whole?for example, for the client it may be connect->channelActive->channelRead->readComplete(maybe not right).Just like this.Thanks!